# Jackrabbit/Modeshape data migration requires adding properties to frozen nodes

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr, modeshape

We are working on a migration tool for moving data from an older version to a newer version of a custom system that is based on a JCR implementation (either Jackrabbit or Modeshape).
 Our problem is related to JCR versioning support for some type of custom nodes.
 Migration requires adding new properties to that custom nodes and implicitly to all versions of that node therefore requiring adding new properties to frozen nodes.
  As frozen nodes are read-only, is there a workaround that would allow changing their content?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way in either ModeShape or Jackrabbit to modify the version history without explicitly checking out those older versions and then checking them back it. But that will essentially branch the version history at all checked-in versions. That's probably not very attractive.

Comment: I made as simple test having version 1.0 and 1.1 on a versionable node. After restoring 1.0 and checked in the changes I have a new version node created as 1.0.0. Unfortunately I can't remove 1.0 as it is referenced.